# Disable mode Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I need to make a button disable if the following condition is present:

If `TextInput1` is completed and combobox1 is blank, button disabled.

I am using:

```
If(IsBlank(ComboBox1.Selected.Mail) and (TextInput1.Text), Disabled,Edit)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "TextInput1 is completed"? Do you mean when textbox is not blank/empty?

Comment: Ganesh, formula worked as I wanted. Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
If(IsBlank(ComboBox1.Selected.Mail) && Not(IsBlank(TextInput1.Text)), Disabled, Edit)
```